# how to get one side of entity in onetomany relation with react native

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, jhipster

I create application with jhipster and ignite cli. Application is task manager for a users. Every user hava multiple tasks. But task can have only one user. When i click to see detail of task it shows id, name, and deadline date but it doesnt show username who should own that task. I am new on React Native. I use java spring boot backend side.

This is my render in task_detail.js

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container} testID="taskDetailScrollView">
   <Text style={styles.text}>ID: {this.props.task.id}</Text>
   <Text testID="task" style={styles.text}>Task: {this.props.task.task}</Text>
   <Text testID="deadline" style={styles.text}>Deadline: {String(this.props.task.deadline)}</Text>
   <Text style={styles.text}>User: {this.props.task.user_id}</Text>
   <RoundedButton text="Edit" onPress={taskEntityEditScreen.bind(this, { entityId: this.props.task.id })} />
   <RoundedButton text="Delete" onPress={this.confirmDelete} />
</ScrollView>
```

This is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   Navigation.events().bindComponent(this)
   this.props.getTask(this.props.data.entityId)
}
```

And i have foreign key of user_id in task table. I need to get username from that foreign key user_id.

Comment: This does not look like an issue within the React code, did you inspect the JSON response returned by backend? I suspect that it does not include the related entity.

Comment: api bring data like this 
````
{
  "id" : 1,
  "task" : "(Chagos Gorgeous Frozen",
  "deadline" : "2021-09-24T09:55:00+03:00",
  "user" : {
    "id" : 1052,
    "login" : "kaan",
    "firstName" : null,
    "lastName" : null,
    "email" : "kaganince1@hotmail.com",
    "activated" : true,
    "langKey" : "en",
    "imageUrl" : null,
    "resetDate" : null
  }
```
I need to take user.login to that text area

Comment: I tried to use like this.props.task.user.login but didnt work

Comment: OK, so JSON response is correct, I'm an Angular guy so I can't help on the React part but have you run your app under Chrome debugger to inspect variables while stepping into your code?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Learning how to use Chrome debugger is a required basic skill for frontend development. You'll find plenty of tutorials by searching on Google, here is one: https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome